# how to get all data as list by using createCriteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have table structure like

```
id bigint(20) NOT NULL
version bigint(20) NOT NULL 
name varchar(255) NOT NULL
department_id bigint(20) NOT NULL
```

Here `department_id` is a foreign key and has a *belongs to* relationship, so how can I get all elements, where `department_id = 2`,

how can I do this in grails by using `createCriteria()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Criteria like this.

```
def criteria = TableName.createCriteria()
        def records = criteria.list() {
            eq('department_id', '2')

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def results = c.list() {
        eq('room.id', Long.valueOf(praramsId))
        order(sortColumn, sSortDir)
    }
```

Comment: This answer ended up in the low-quality review queue. Could you edit it to add some explanation of what this code does and how it solves the question?